# DisplayTag and Tiles

Tags: java, jsp, tiles, displaytag

I'm building a Table using **DisplayTag** Library. I need to share a column among many tables in many pages, so I'm trying to insert `<display:column>` inside `<display:table>` by using `<tiles:insertAttribute>`:

```
    <display:table ....>       
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="attivoTh"/>    
    </display:table> 

 <definition name="attivoTh" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/th/attivoTh.jsp" />
```

This is the error I get:

```
 nov 21, 2016 2:08:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ds] in context with path [/Jeans2016] threw
 exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
 is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including
 path '/WEB-INF/template/default/template1.jsp'.] with root cause
 Exception: [.ColumnTag] Tag "column" should ne nested in "table"
```

Does anybody understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Your display table uses a collection. 
In that collection you put objects.
If many different tables use the same value/object then provide that object in the collection server side.
(You could use a wrapper for that)

For your object Foo in the provided then just

```
<display:table ....>       
        <display:column property="foo.value" .../>    
</display:table>
```

Or,all your servlets that show these tables could be extended from a base servlet that puts that object/value in the request and add a column with that data :

```
<display:table ....>       
        <display:column ...>    
        ${foo.value}
        </display:column>    
</display:table>
```